# Npm generate error when installing module

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

This is error

```
npm WARN bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.12.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Peer dependencies are NO LONGER INSTALLED AUTOMATICALLY from version 3.0

https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.0.0

You have to install it manually and make it part of your npm package.

```
npm install popper.js@^1.12.3 --save
```

Comment: When i entered this command than generate another error :  npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.12.3: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm ERR! code ENOSELF
npm ERR! Refusing to install package with name "popper.js" under a package
npm ERR! also called "popper.js". Did you name your project the same
npm ERR! as the dependency you're installing? -@twboc

Comment: Ok. In this case try installing the @popperjs/core and see if it still meets the dependency. For your information not having all peer dependencies does not mean that your app will not work.